# Is it possible to play multiple mp4 audio tracks at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm trying out the audioTracks property of the HTML video element in both Chrome and Safari (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioTrack)

What is not clear is whether or not you can enabled multiple tracks at the same time.

In my tests I have a file with 8 audio tracks. The first one is enabled as you expect and plays just fine. I use Javascript to enabled the second track with

```
const videoplayer = document.getQuerySelector(".videoplayer");
videoplayer.audioTracks[1].enabled = true;
```

Now it begins playing the second audio track. However, the first one is no longer heard. However if I console.log the `videoplayer.audioTracks` I can see that the enabled property on the first track is still true.

In most cases it totally makes sense to mute all other tracks when enabled an audio track, but I'm curious why the api doesn't reflect this in the audioTracks object.

Thanks